# Problems creating a basic clock with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, clock

I'm trying to build just a simple clock using javascript, but I'm at a loss at to why it isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateTime() {
        var now = newDate();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var minutes = now.getMinutes();
        var seconds = now.getSeconds();

        var currenTime = hours + ':' + minutes ':' + seconds;

        var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
        counter.innerHTML = currentTime;
    }
    updateTime();
});
```

Comment: What is `newDate` function? Shouldn't it be `new Date()`? If it should be, how comes that you didn't check console to fix this simple typographical error?

Comment: Please explain what the problem is - eg error messages.

Comment: You call it once at `domready` but you expect it to update as time goes on? You need an `interval` after you fix the `new Date()`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I changed new Date(), and I will need to set an interval to update, but the problem is that I'm just not getting the time to display at all.  I have div with id 'counter'.  I also saw that I spelled the var currenTime instead of currentTime, but even fixing that didn't cause it to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `newDate()// wrong`
   should be new Date();
2. `counter.innerHTML = currenTime;`
   should be   `counter.innerHTML = currentTime;`
3. use a `setInterval`

http://jsfiddle.net/rkv0deqc/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var counter = document.getElementById('counter');


window.setInterval(function() {
    console.log(1);
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();

    var currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes +':' + seconds;


    counter.innerHTML = currentTime;
}


    ,'1000');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to fix bugs in your code:

1. space between `new` and `Date` (`new Date`).
2. typo in `var currenTime` -> `var currentTime`
3. missing `+`after `minutes` in `var currentTime`

Later, in case you want to make a real time clock, you need to use `setInterval` to call `updateTime` every second.

```
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

Like this.

And of course define `<div id="counter"></div>` in your html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var minutes = now.getMinutes();
        var seconds = now.getSeconds();

        var currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

        var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
        counter.innerHTML = currentTime;
    }
    updateTime();
    setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: You get a tree of updateTime calls here.. Poor.

Comment: What tree? `setInterval` will run this method every one second. Please propose a better solution

Comment: and each method call runs another setInterval

Comment: just change `setInterval` to `setTimeout` or move your `setInterval` outside of `updateTime`

Comment: Yes right sorry ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You missed the white space between `new` and `Date()`. You really should take a look at devtools before this.
2. Your function is executed at DOM ready, and it's done. What you want is to update every second. You need a `setInterval`, or recusive `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     function countdown(id, timer){

    timer--;

    daysRemain = Math.floor(timer / 86400);

    amount = timer%86400;
    hrsRemain  = Math.floor(amount / 3600);

     amount = timer%3600;
    minsRemain = Math.floor(amount/60);

     amount = timer%60;
    secsRemain =Math.floor(amount);

    // Pad the string with leading 0 if less than 2 chars long
    if (secsRemain.length < 2) {
        secsRemain = '0' + secsRemain;
    }

    // String format the remaining time
    clock      = daysRemain + ":" + hrsRemain + ":" + minsRemain + ":" + secsRemain;

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock;
    if ( timer > 0 ) {

        // Time still remains, call this function again in 1 sec
        setTimeout("countdown('" + id + "'," + timer + ")", 1000);


    } else {
        // Time is out! Hide the countdown
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'Time Expired';

    }
    }
```

this is another way using javascript to create the timer clock